# start process in background, get PID, and write into stdin in Shell

Tags: linux, shell

I need to do a buffer overflow for my system security course. Therefore I do have a program(called canary) I need start which asks for a input string (read()). 
I need to calculate a canary(random canary built with PID and time) for a successful buffer overflow. I already wrote a program(getcanary) which gets me the right canary. The problem:
I try to start canary in a extra terminal, then get the PID of it, then calculate the program followed by a write to canary's STDIN. The last thing is where I have a Problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start canary"
x-terminal-emulator -e ./canary &
sleep 1
PID=$(pgrep canary)
CANARY=$(./getcanary $PID)
```

How can I write the command to the extra terminal? I already tried several solutions,

```
echo "cmd" > /proc/$PID/fd/0
```

is one of it
I also tried

```
mkfifo fifo
cat > fifo &
./canary < fifo
echo "cmd" > fifo
```

some other solutions are not allowed by my environment, as the script must run on a clean install of xubuntu, so I can't use screen or tmux

I hope you can help me,
Thank you! :)

PS.: I'm sorry if I misunderstood any of these solutions I tried, I'm not very familiar with shell scripting.

Comment: Put the write into the code that's performed inside the terminal emulator, rather than trying to do it from outside. For example: `x-terminal-emulator -e 'echo "cmd" | ./canary'`

Comment: Thank you, the problem is, I need the canary first to build the right canary (otherwise the buffer overflow won't be successful) therefore I need the PID of the canary process and therefore I need to start the process at first

Comment: Let's back up here a bit. Why are you running a terminal emulator at all?

Comment: The easy way to do this is to run the program as a bash [coproc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html), assuming you *don't* really need the terminal.

Comment: `coproc { canary; }` puts the PID of the canary in `$COPROC_PID`, lets you write to it with `echo "something" >&${COPROC[1]}`, and lets you read from it with `read varname <&${COPROC[0]}`.

Comment: (Ob-random-aside: Seeing folks learning to break systems before they've spent years doing system-level development, preferably in C, seems a bit cart-before-the-horse -- if you have experience with the compromises folks make in design and development time, that makes you a much more capable reverse engineer than someone who has a library of tools/techniques but no basis to understand when/why/how the systems they're breaking are structured as they are).

Comment: (...which is to say that while it's not unusual for someone not to be familiar with the finer points of shell scripting, I'd hope for anyone doing actual security work in the field to know enough about how FIFOs work at the OS level -- regardless of the language used -- to recognize the errors in the last code segment given, and also to have enough sense to follow the process tree from the child they forked off rather than doing a blind `pgrep`).

Comment: Thank you, I just got it to work with a fifo :)
I'm a student in the 3rd semster doing a 5th semester course as I hove some time left. I do have skills in C and Java programming, but this course requires a script (.sh, .py,...) and sadly I never wrote a script like that before.

Comment: Good to hear. To be a little more direct, `./canary & canary_pid=$!` will get you your PID without any mucking around with `pgrep`. (After all, starting a process is a `fork()` and `execve()`; if you're the parent, then you necessarily know the child's PID, because it was returned to you by the `fork` call).

Answer (score 2):

Write to the terminal, not to the running process!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start canary"
x-terminal-emulator -e ./canary &
termpid=$!
sleep 1
xvkbd -window $(xdotool search --sync --pid $termpid) -text "echo Hello world!\n"
```